# Pandas: Combination of two data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames, `old` and `new`. Both have identical columns.

I want to, by the index,

- Add rows to `old` that exist in `new` but not in `old`
- Update rows at `old` with data in `new`.

Is there any efficient way of doing so in `pandas`? I found [update()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), which does exactly the second step. However, it doesn't add rows. I could do the first step using some set logic onto the indices. However, that does not appear to efficient. What's the best way to do these two operations?

#### Example

`old`

```
    a   b
0   1   1
1   3   3
```

`new`

```
    a   b
1   1   2
2   1   2
```

`result`

```
    a   b
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   1   2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first find common indices for both dataframes then for first with that indices assign values of the second. And then you'll get the result with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
In [35]: df1
Out[35]:
   a  b
0  1  1
1  3  3

In [36]: df2
Out[36]:
   a  b
1  1  2
2  1  2

idx = df1.index & df2.index
df1.loc[idx, :] = df2.loc[idx, :]
df1 = df1.combine_first(df2)

In [39]: df1
Out[39]:
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the first step using `df.reindex()`method

```
old = old.reindex(index=new.index)
```